# In magento i have a issue with my admin page. When i save information of brand extension of magestore how to solve this following error?

Tags: php, database, magento, mage

In magento i have a problem with my admin page.I installed one brand Extension of Magestore when i save information of brand at that time it generate error like following how i can solve this error ?

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'eldorado_mage.enterprise_url_rewrite' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

your magento installation do not have the table 'enterprise_url_rewrite', please check your extension and find the sql from there and run/create the same table in your database.